# Is there possible to include Filesize in metadata file same before xml metadata?

Tags: c#

In old xml metadata, There is filename and filesize properties are exists but in the new CSV metadata file have only the filename but missing filesize.

Is there is a way to add extended properties to enable this file size for each mail box document? This is helpful to read the file size to tracking.

Thanks,

While doing migrations from Google vault to another account. We are calculating the size of mailboxes migrated using metadata.

Now we don't a options to calculate the file size.

Thanks,